# Apache SOLR Exception with docID

Tags: solr, websphere, wcs

Getting below exception when I hit search Rest API in WebSphere Commerce.

SolrCore      E org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=56299 (got docID=56393)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.component.solr.SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.process(SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.java:1645)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:218)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:150)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:91)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:310)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.util.SearchQueryHelper.internalQuery(SearchQueryHelper.java:358)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.util.SearchQueryHelper.query(SearchQueryHelper.java:121)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.rest.search.processor.solr.SolrRESTSearchExpressionProcessor.performSearch(SolrRESTSearchExpressionProcessor.java:525)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.search.SearchServiceFacade.performSearch(SearchServiceFacade.java:193)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.search.handler.v2_0.AbstractSearchResourceHandler.executeSearch(AbstractSearchResourceHandler.java:486)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.search.handler.v2_0.AbstractSearchResourceHandler.performSearch(AbstractSearchResourceHandler.java:317)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.search.handler.v2_0.ProductViewHandler.findProductsBySearchTerm(ProductViewHandler.java:615)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.rest.handlers.AbstractCommerceTokenRequestHandler.handleRequest(AbstractCommerceTokenRequestHandler.java:110)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.rest.handlers.search.solr.SolrRESTSearchCommerceIdentityRequestHandler.handleRequest(SolrRESTSearchCommerceIdentityRequestHandler.java:117)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.rest.handlers.RequestPerformanceMeasurementHandler.handleRequest(RequestPerformanceMeasurementHandler.java:98)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.servlet.filter.HttpSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityFilter.java:268)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.caching.RESTCacheFilter.doFilter(RESTCacheFilter.java:448)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.filter.RestTransactionFilter.doFilter(RestTransactionFilter.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.commerce.rest.caching.RESTInvalidationFilter.doFilter(RESTInvalidationFilter.java:78)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=56299 (got docID=56393)
at org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.readerIndex(BaseCompositeReader.java:182)
at org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.document(BaseCompositeReader.java:109)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.document(IndexReader.java:460)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.doc(SolrIndexSearcher.java:697)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.doc(SolrIndexSearcher.java:625)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.component.solr.SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.process(SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.java:1613)

API where this exception comes - /search/resources/store//productview/bySearchTerm, /search/resources/store/10151/productview/byCategory/

This exception is not seen everytime.

Comment: which version of solr are you using

Comment: version is 4.10.3

Comment: may be this because of the segment issue? is the indexed are corrupted or do you have any kind of customization while quering the data

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti , Can you please explain this issue . Actually I have not made any recent configuration change for SOLR and this issue pops up all of a sudden . This is where I am confused. Index is not corrupted